# How can I add a configuration to my application after build?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I have built an app with Electron and Electron Builder.

My app requires an API key to work, which should be generated when users download my app. My application somehow needs to know this API key in order to recognise the user.

However, I can't put the key statically into my codebase, because it will be generated for every user, which would require me to compile the app for every user with the appropriate API key.

Is there an easy way to create a configuration file in a second step after building my application or how would I solve this problem?

Comment: Does the key need to be bundled with your app? Can't you let your users enter the key manually and store it from the application?

Comment: Yeah, would be fantastic and simple, if I could. But, from specifics I need the auto configuration, without the user put nothing in the app. they should only download and start to use app.